# Cast - Intterupt with temp stream - Resume original

Tags: casting, chromecast

I would like to be able to pause a currently playing steam ...
i.e. music or video ...

Then play a TextToSpeech stream  ... then resume the original stream.
Should that be an easy use-case ? 
(I already have the ability to pause and play the TextToSpeech stream using the default media player)
I capture the original App and Media object ... but can't seem to restart them.
I can launch the original app ... but I can seem to it to load the media.
The app I am interrupting for testing is "Tune In"

Comment: Can you show the code that you have done, so the other member here in this community will understand better the things that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You only have control over your own app; you can pause the playback of video from a different app but you cannot "pause" an app, load your own app and then "resume" the other app when you're done with your own app. When you load your own app, you are terminating the other app and from that point on, there isn't much you can do to "resume" the other app to the state it was (=(unless you own the other app, too).